# Leading zeros on RSA

Tags: encryption, rsa

I saw that in many implementations of RSA they added **random** leading bits to the plain text when it was too small, and wrote in the beginning where the real pain text begins. Then encrypted it.
Is there a reason not to put leading zeros instead? Or 1 followed by leading zeros? 
Does that creates some sort of weakness in the encryption?

Comment: This question "Why use random padding in RSA encryption" is off-topic on stackoverflow. It might be on-topic in [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) except it has already been [answered there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/why-is-padding-used-for-rsa-encryption-given-that-it-is-not-a-block-cipher).